# Slice MongoDB array to get all starting from specified index

Tags: mongodb

I understand that `slice` allows to specify start and number of items we need. But how can i get all elements in an array starting from a specific position? Something like this

```
{fieldToProject: { $slice: [ 1, { $size: '$fieldToProject' } ], }}
```

which should give me all elements from position 1 onwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$slice` aggregate operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      item: 1,
      slicedColors: {
        $slice: [
          "$colors",
          3,
          {
            $size: "$colors"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zSlMiXlUqEX)